# State management technique in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, state

I have my project like Uber (Cab Booking) but confused to choose better state management.
suggest me best state management for better performance and code structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Bloc, which is commonly used by many programmers
Read more here: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/

Comment: You have any Idea of getX?